# Installing IIS Express 32-bit on a 64-bit operating system using MAC Parallels Windows 7

Tags: macos, windows-7, iis-express, parallels

I am using a mac, with Parallels to access Windows 7 in a virtual machine. On the Windows 7 side, I have tried to install IIS Express 8.0 but get the following error:

The 32 bit-version of iis 8.0 express cannot be installed on a 64-bit edition of microsoft windows.

I know the 32-bit is part of the deal when installing iis 8.0 express. Is there anyway around this?

Thanls

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running Windows 7 64 bit, so download and install the 64 bit version of IIS Express 8.0:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34679

If you click download on that page you'll be given the the option to download the 64 bit edition:

```
iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi
```

Installing the 64 bit edition will install both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions:

> http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme

From the "read me":

> When you install IIS 8.0 Express on a 64-bit system, both the 32-bit
>   and 64-bit versions of IIS 8.0 Express will be installed respectively
>   in the "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express" and "%ProgramFiles%\IIS
>   Express" folders.